# depends_on is not running in appropriate order

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've got a small docker-compose file that isn't running in the appropriate order.

I need to spin up the db (`mssql` service) before spinning up the `python` service - I've read about `depends_on` and I've set it up so the `python` service should be the last one spinning up - but it doesn't work.

It continuously fires up `ubuntu`, then `python`, which doesn't work because it needs the database to be available.

```
version: '3'

services:
  mssql:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:latest-ubuntu"
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "123456"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
  python:
    build:
      context: ./build
      dockerfile: python.dock
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - .:/home/code
    depends_on:
      - ubuntu
      - mssql
  ubuntu:
    build:
      context: ./build
      dockerfile: ubuntu.dock
    volumes:
      - ./transfer:/home/
    ports:
      - "60000:22"
```

Any thoughts what might becausing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From docker compose `depends_on` documentation:

> There are several things to be aware of when using depends_on:
>
> depends_on does not wait for db and redis to be “ready” before
>   starting web - only until they have been started.

This line means that `depends_on` doesn't guarantee that dependent service is READY to serve requests, it guarantees that dependent service was just STARTED.

[Depends_on documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on)

[Start up order documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/)

Comment: When I run `docker-compose --build up` I see it start up `ubuntu`, then it immediately starts `python`, it doesn't even start up `mssql`... am I missing something?

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't start mssql?

Comment: In the terminal it says that it's building ubuntu, then it says it's building python. Am I confusing start order with build order?

Comment: I guess so. Main point here is that you can't rely on "depends_on", it just guarantees that db will START before service, not that it will be READY to serve requests. You should write custom script to check if database is actually READY.